# NSDecimalNumber for finances

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber, nsdecimalnumber

I'm building an app that deals with money and I've been using floating point arithmetic up until now, but I've learned that it's better to use NSDecimalNumber.

I want to make sure that I've understood it correctly, so here goes:

Imagine some worker, earning 20.57$/hour. This information is provided by the user. I did it like this before:

```
@property (nonatomic) float hourlyRate;

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSNumber *hourlyRate = [numberFormatter numberFromString:self.rateTextField.text];
settingsObject.hourlyRate = [hourlyRate floatValue];
```

But I've now changed it to:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSDecimalNumber *hourlyRate;

settingsObject.hourlyRate = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.rateTextField.text locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

**Is this the correct way to read NSDecimalNumbers from string?**

Say this person enters a workplace at 10:01. I save that information like so:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"start"];
```

Once the person is finished, the start time is read from NSUserDefaults like so:

```
NSDate *start = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"start"];
```

The duration is calculated like so:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start] / 3600;

NSDecimalNumber *earned = [settingsObject.hourlyRate decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:interval]];
```

**is this the correct and most efficient way, while keeping precision?**

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use float, use double. float has six decimals precision, double has 15. float gives measurable errors in an annual salary.

Comment: @gnasher729 I see. How well does this solution work opposed to the answer by Rainer Schwarze? What's your opinion on this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct way to read NSDecimalNumbers from string?

Yes. However, you shouldn't need to cast the result. So it should just look like this:

```
settingsObject.hourlyRate = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.rateTextField.text locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

And the `NSLocale` part isn't necessary, unless you're using a non-current locale:

```
settingsObject.hourlyRate = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.rateTextField.text];
```

I don't think this function likes nil values, so you would want to make sure that `rateTextField` has a non-nil value first:

```
if ([self.rateTextField hasText]) {
    settingsObject.hourlyRate = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.rateTextField.text];
}
else {
    settingsObject.hourlyRate = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
}
```

> is this the correct and most efficient way, while keeping precision?

Yes, your conversion of the interval to an NSDecimal number and then the multiplication looks good to me.

Comment: it seems like this is the best way to handle money calculations. Take the work hour tracker for instance, is it really necessary to use NSDecimalNumber or will double deliver? Look at Rainer Schwarze's answer please.

Comment: Double works fine when accuracy isn't that important. But I use it anytime I'm working with money. It's no more difficult to use than floating values, and I think the code is clearer than trying to remember everywhere you need to multiply or divide by 100 with integers.

Comment: Yeah. So you would suggest using double for a work tracking app? Doing arithmetics on NSDecimalNumbers are incredibly hopeless imo, you have to do like numberOne = [numberOne decimalNumberByAdding:numberTwo]; instead of simply numberOne += numberTwo; which, indeed, makes the code a LOT harder to maintain, read and work with.

Comment: Since you're dealing with money (hourlyRate), yes, I would use NSDecimalNumber. I've never found it any more cumbersome than anything else in Objective-C.

Comment: I see. Not really sure what to do, a lot of people say Double will be fine, but some also say use NSDecimalNumber. But you have to agree that many, many lines like  [numberOne decimalNumberByAdding:numberTwo]; is a lot harder to read and maintain that numberOne += numberTwo; ?

Comment: No, I don't think it's harder to read or maintain. You're going to end up with a project with tens of thousands of lines of Objective-C code. The extra 100 we're talking about are not going to be a big deal. You should choose the best model for the data, not the one that's easiest for you.

Comment: Yes. As I'm multiplying with an NSTimeInterval, wouldn't the rounding issue arise there aswell? Considering I'll be initializing NSDecimalNumber from an interval

Comment: Converting a double to an NSDecimalNumber (or the other way) won't result in any rounding errors. That happens when you do multiplication and division. So convert to an NSDecimalNumber first, then do the math, and you should have no problems.

Comment: I see. Doing this: NSDecimalNumber *floatDecimal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:42.13f]; uses the NSNumber initialiser - will that cause any problems?

Comment: I'm taking the leap and jumping into the water. Converting everything to use NSDecimalNumber now

Comment: That won't cause any problems. NSDecimalNumber is a subclass of NSNumber, so all of the NSNumber functions are available for you to use safely.

Comment: Nice, almost done with converting to NSDecimalNumber now

Answer (score 0):

First you need an answer for this question:

**How accurate do you want to be - or do you need to be?**

Will your app generate invoices, or will it serve as the basis for invoices? If yes, you may have to stay away from floating point numbers. You may also have to think about how duration is actually used in calculations. There may be regulations for certain business areas or  professions, which define how to measure / invoice time.

**Not really accurate:**

If you do not need to be really accurate, I would continue using floating numbers until you hit obstacles.

**Accurate:**

**1. Money:**

Store money as integers as cents.

**2. Time:**

Determine time slots and store them as integers (maybe minutes).

**3. Calculations:**

Calculate using integers. Never use floats.

---

**Details:**

When you have an input like `25.07` (I used a different number than your 20.57 to explain cents rendering) store it as `2507`. Do your calculations in cents. For displaying convert to `$` or `$/hrs`. For example:

```
int amount = 2507;
int amountDollars = amount / 100;
int amountCents = amount % 100;

NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%02d $/hrs", amountDollars, amountCents];
NSLog(@"output = %@", output);
// prints:
// output = 25.07 $/hrs
```

For time chose a suitable base unit (minute / second / five minutes / ten minutes / half an hour?) and store that as an integer.

Lets assume you invoice in units of 10 minutes. You probably then bill the next 10 minutes, when they are begun. So if 11 minutes are in the record, you have to calculate 20 minutes. Similar issues exist for minutes - assume these values:

```
Actual Time | "Integer Time"
10:09:59    |  10:09
10:10:01    |  10:10
Difference:
00:00:02    |  00:01
```

If you just use actual time using floating points the first difference amounts to almost nothing - the second amounts to one minute. If your times are shown in the report as `10:09` and `10:10`, people will wonder, why in the first case the amount is almost nothing.

Doing financial and time calculations is hard if you need to be really accurate. So it boils down to this: First find out, how accurate you need to be. (Note that "accurate" may have weird meanings and implications when entering the realm of regulations, laws etc.)

Comment: Very detailed answer! Thanks! Storing as cents, or rather 100x what the user provides for hourly rate is a good idea, I'll implement that and get rid of the floats. I've wrote a custom object to store the time values which also implements a custom getter and setter method that automatically omits seconds. So I'm dealing with whole minutes at the moment. I'm only storing time and calculating the currency at run time when needed. The only financial value I'm storing is the hourly rate. The user may choose to use the information for invoices, but it is basically meant to keep track of working.

Comment: @Erik Sure - could you take care of starting the chat?

Comment: I'll try to be in the chat room whenever you got time :)